# Laravel 5.5: Query Building with Join and Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have Two Tables

```
'Orders' with Columns 

['subtotal', 'taxes', 'delivery_fee', 'total', 'discount', 'status', 'delivery_status','payment_status', 'special_instructions', 'address_id', 'store_id', 'user_id', 'delivery_profile_id','payment_method_id', 'type', 'scheduled_on'];
```

And

```
'Stores' with Columns

['name', 'tagline', 'image_url', 'delivery_time', 'minimum_order','delivery_fee', 'details', 'delivery_limit', 'area', 'address', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'preorder','serves_non_veg', 'cost_for_two', 'status', 'owner_id', 'apibot', 'admin_id','admin_mobile', 'opens_at', 'closes_at'];
```

Iam running a Laravel 5.5 Framework and Having Tough time to build a Query. Below is my Complete Code fr returning the Order List according to requested Status from my Mobile API

```
        $orders = Order::where('store_id', Auth::user()->store->id);

        if($request->status) {
            $orders = $orders->where('status', $request->status);
        }

        // filter for active orders
        if($request->active_orders) {
            $orders = $orders->whereIn('status', ['new', 'accepted', 'preparing', 'dispatched']);
        }

        // for delivery tab in store app
        if($request->deliveries) {
            $orders = $orders->whereIn('status', ['accepted', 'preparing', 'dispatched'])
                ->where('delivery_profile_id', '<>', null)
                ->whereIn('delivery_status', ['allotted', 'started', 'complete']);
        }
```

In the Below Code I need to put a Join and Where Clause combination to Join Store with Orders

```
$orders = Order::where('store_id', Auth::user()->store->id);
```

For Example: General SQL Query as Follows

```
   Select * From Orders, Stores Where Stores.id=Orders.store_id and Stores.admin_id = 17
```

I tried with Possible solutions but not successful. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to create a `belongsTo` on the `Store` model to create a relationship:

```
public function store() {
   return $this->belongsTo(\App\Store::class);
}
```

Then your query will look like:

```
$orders = Order::with(['store' => function($query) {
    return $query->where('admin_id', auth()->user->id)
}]);
```

Comment: Hi Sorry to Say its not Working

I already Had
public function store()
    {
        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Store', 'store_id');
        
    }
after your proposed changes My APi returns Error

Comment: Hai Fixed the Error
Auth() was the error
changed to Auth::user()

Comment: Apologies. You should also be able to use the `auth()` helper. I will update the code.

Comment: I have issue with FCM request for Push Notifications
$this->pushNotifications[] = new PushNotification($this->order->store->user->fcm_registration_id,
                'New Order', 'You have received new order 00'. $this->order->id , ["order_id" => $this->order->id]);

How do I call admin_id based User->fcmRegistration?

Answer (score 0):

See if it works like this for you:

```
$result = DB::table('Orders as o')
->join('Stores as s', 's.id', '=', 'o.store_id')
->where('s.admin_id', auth()->user->id)
->get();
```

Comment: Not Working Sorry

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

```
$orders = Order::with(['store' => function($query) {
return $query->where('admin_id', auth()->user->id)}]);
```

New Query regarding the same Join and WHere Clause

$this->pushNotifications[] = new PushNotification($this->order->store->user->fcm_registration_id, 'New Order', 'New Order');

How do I call admin_id based User->fcmRegistration?
I tried with 
$this->order->store->'admin_id'->user->fcm_registration_id had No Luck.

Kindly Help.